# On Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu 22.04 don't work ioctl

Tags: raspberry-pi, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ioctl, realsense

I have Raspberry Pi 4 (aarch64 Cortex-A72) with OS Ubuntu 22.04 LTS 64-bit installed. I try read frame from webcam Intel RealSense ID Solution F455.

```
buffer V4lNode::Read()
{
    buffer res;
    struct v4l2_buffer buf = {0};
    struct timeval tv = {0}; 
    tv.tv_sec = 0; // max time to wait for next frame
    tv.tv_usec =100;

    buf.type = _type;
    buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
    buf.index = 0;

    fd_set fds;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(_fd, &fds);
    ThrowIfFailed("wait for frame", select(_fd, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv));

    if (ioctl(_fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &buf) == FAILED_V4L){ // dequeue frame from buffer.
        std::cout << "V4lNode failed  dequeue frame from buffer: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return res; //returns zero-length buffer
    }
    res = _buffers[buf.index];
    res.size = buf.bytesused;
    
    buf.type = _type; 
    buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
    ThrowIfFailed("qbuffer", ioctl(_fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &buf)); // queue next frame

    return res;
}
```

When I run this code:

```
if (ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &buf) < 0) {
    std::cout << "V4lNode failed  dequeue frame from buffer: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
}
```

I get output result:

*V4lNode failed dequeue frame from buffer: Resource temporarily unavailable*

But device opened success:

```
fd = open(path.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK, 0);
std::cout << "V4lNode open files discription: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
```

Output result:

*V4lNode open files discription: Success*

When I run this command in terminal:

```
pi@pi:~$ v4l2-compliance
v4l2-compliance 1.22.1, 64 bits, 64-bit time_t

Compliance test for uvcvideo device /dev/video0:
```

I get error:

```
Control ioctls (Input 0):
        fail: v4l2-test-controls.cpp(246): missing control class for class 00980000
    test VIDIOC_QUERY_EXT_CTRL/QUERYMENU: FAIL
```

Full tets output:

```
pi@pi:~$ v4l2-compliance 
v4l2-compliance 1.22.1, 64 bits, 64-bit time_t

Compliance test for uvcvideo device /dev/video0:

Driver Info:
    Driver name      : uvcvideo
    Card type        : Intel F450
    Bus info         : usb-0000:01:00.0-1.1
    Driver version   : 5.15.39
    Capabilities     : 0x84a00001
        Video Capture
        Metadata Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
        Device Capabilities
    Device Caps      : 0x04200001
        Video Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
Media Driver Info:
    Driver name      : uvcvideo
    Model            : Intel F450
    Serial           : 00.00.01
    Bus info         : usb-0000:01:00.0-1.1
    Media version    : 5.15.39
    Hardware revision: 0x00000100 (256)
    Driver version   : 5.15.39
Interface Info:
    ID               : 0x03000002
    Type             : V4L Video
Entity Info:
    ID               : 0x00000001 (1)
    Name             : Intel F450
    Function         : V4L2 I/O
    Flags            : default
    Pad 0x01000007   : 0: Sink
      Link 0x02000010: from remote pad 0x100000a of entity 'Extension 3' (Video Pixel Formatter): Data, Enabled, Immutable

Required ioctls:
    test MC information (see 'Media Driver Info' above): OK
    test VIDIOC_QUERYCAP: OK
    test invalid ioctls: OK

Allow for multiple opens:
    test second /dev/video0 open: OK
    test VIDIOC_QUERYCAP: OK
    test VIDIOC_G/S_PRIORITY: OK
    test for unlimited opens: OK

Debug ioctls:
    test VIDIOC_DBG_G/S_REGISTER: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_LOG_STATUS: OK (Not Supported)

Input ioctls:
    test VIDIOC_G/S_TUNER/ENUM_FREQ_BANDS: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_G/S_FREQUENCY: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_S_HW_FREQ_SEEK: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_ENUMAUDIO: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_G/S/ENUMINPUT: OK
    test VIDIOC_G/S_AUDIO: OK (Not Supported)
    Inputs: 1 Audio Inputs: 0 Tuners: 0

Output ioctls:
    test VIDIOC_G/S_MODULATOR: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_G/S_FREQUENCY: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_ENUMAUDOUT: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_G/S/ENUMOUTPUT: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_G/S_AUDOUT: OK (Not Supported)
    Outputs: 0 Audio Outputs: 0 Modulators: 0

Input/Output configuration ioctls:
    test VIDIOC_ENUM/G/S/QUERY_STD: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_ENUM/G/S/QUERY_DV_TIMINGS: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_DV_TIMINGS_CAP: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_G/S_EDID: OK (Not Supported)

Control ioctls (Input 0):
        fail: v4l2-test-controls.cpp(246): missing control class for class 00980000
    test VIDIOC_QUERY_EXT_CTRL/QUERYMENU: FAIL
    test VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL: OK
    test VIDIOC_G/S_CTRL: OK
        warn: v4l2-test-controls.cpp(757): g_ext_ctrls(0) invalid error_idx 0
    test VIDIOC_G/S/TRY_EXT_CTRLS: OK
    test VIDIOC_(UN)SUBSCRIBE_EVENT/DQEVENT: OK
    test VIDIOC_G/S_JPEGCOMP: OK (Not Supported)
    Standard Controls: 1 Private Controls: 0

Format ioctls (Input 0):
    test VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT/FRAMESIZES/FRAMEINTERVALS: OK
    test VIDIOC_G/S_PARM: OK
    test VIDIOC_G_FBUF: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_G_FMT: OK
    test VIDIOC_TRY_FMT: OK
        warn: v4l2-test-formats.cpp(1036): Could not set fmt2
    test VIDIOC_S_FMT: OK
    test VIDIOC_G_SLICED_VBI_CAP: OK (Not Supported)
    test Cropping: OK (Not Supported)
    test Composing: OK (Not Supported)
    test Scaling: OK (Not Supported)

Codec ioctls (Input 0):
    test VIDIOC_(TRY_)ENCODER_CMD: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_G_ENC_INDEX: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_(TRY_)DECODER_CMD: OK (Not Supported)

Buffer ioctls (Input 0):
    test VIDIOC_REQBUFS/CREATE_BUFS/QUERYBUF: OK
    test VIDIOC_EXPBUF: OK
    test Requests: OK (Not Supported)

Total for uvcvideo device /dev/video0: 46, Succeeded: 45, Failed: 1, Warnings: 2
```

Confuses a lot notes `(Not Supported)`.

**UPD:**

Outputs formats:

```
pi@pi:~$ v4l2-ctl --list-formats
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Type: Video Capture

    [0]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
```

Output `dmesg` errors:

```
[    0.823576] zswap: compressor zstd not available, using default lzo
[    0.829609] zswap: zpool z3fold not available, using default zbud
[  102.238315] uvcvideo 1-1.1:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-1).
[  102.238626] uvcvideo 1-1.1:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-1).
[ 5822.239686] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
[ 5822.249854] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
[ 5822.259913] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
[ 5822.269949] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
[ 5822.280057] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
[ 5822.290139] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
[ 5822.391565] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 5822.401637] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 5822.411679] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 5822.421697] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 5822.431779] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 5822.441885] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 5822.532650] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
[ 5822.563375] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 5822.622056] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
[ 5823.168241] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
[ 5823.270367] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
```

I am tried this solution [Recording usb cam on raspberry pi with ffmpeg - usb troubleshooting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46253564/recording-usb-cam-on-raspberry-pi-with-ffmpeg-usb-troubleshooting) - don't worked

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22 is not supported by realsense yet (setember 7, 2022) acconding to
https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/10439

I was able to run it on Ubuntu 22 only via docker with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.4

WORKDIR /home

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive 
ENV TZ=Europe/Minsk

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \ 
    sudo \ 
    cmake \
    git \
    curl \
    libopencv-dev \ 
    libjpeg-dev \ 
    libpng-dev \ 
    libtiff-dev \  
    libgtk2.0-dev \ 
    python-numpy \ 
    python-pycurl \ 
    keyboard-configuration \
    libgl1-mesa-dev \
    libglu1-mesa-dev \
    libusb-1.0-0-dev \
    libglfw3-dev \
    freeglut3 \
    at \
    freeglut3-dev \
    nano \
    curl \
    libglfw3-dev \
    libgl1-mesa-dev \
    libglu1-mesa-dev \
    at \ 
    udev \
    linux-headers-* \
    libusb-1.0-0-dev 

#update cmake
RUN sudo apt remove cmake -y && \
    wget https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.23.0/cmake-3.23.0.tar.gz && \
    tar -xf cmake-3.23.0.tar.gz && \
    cd cmake-3.23.0 && \
    ./configure && \
    make -j$(nproc)  && \
    sudo make install -j$(nproc) 


#install realsense
RUN git clone https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense && \
    cd librealsense && \
    git checkout v2.51.1 && \
    mkdir -p /etc/udev/rules.d && \
    mkdir build && cd build && \
    cmake .. && \
    make install -j$(nproc) && \
    make -j$(nproc)
```

built as:

```
docker build -t realsense .
```

if you need any GUI to be used, run this before running the container:

```
export DISPLAY=:1
xhost +
```

(maybe you will need to use `DISPLAY=:0` depending on your display index)

and run the container with:

```
sudo docker run -it --privileged -v /etc/udev/*:/etc/udev/* \
    -v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb \
    -v /dev/:/dev/ \
    -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
    -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -h $HOSTNAME -v $HOME/.Xauthority:/home/.Xauthority realsense:latest bash
```